# Can there be two accounts with the same name?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I was quite surprised to see this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas

https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/89316/ste%CC%81phane-chazelas

OK, that's funny: Now it doesn't look like the same any more. When I copied just the name part from the URL and pasted it into my shell it was the same. Probably some UTF encoding stuff, missing normalization or the like?

Comment: [tl;dr yes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25404/213575)

Comment: See [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3230) for _why_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Maybe I am not the only one who gets confused. You could simply add a "This is a clone of that account" and this link to its user page.

Comment: Which prompts the question, "Is it ok to have two (or more) accounts? And what is the limit?" (that would seem to invite abuse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, there can be multiple accounts with the same name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names).

You can choose any name you want as long as:

- it isn't offensive (e.g. stuffing insults into your user name will cause moderators to forcibly rename you and suspend you);
- you aren't impersonating someone. ([Terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) §4: “Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to (…) (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person”.)

Impersonation implies an element of confusion. **It's ok to use the same username as someone else** — for example, there are many users who go by their first name alone, which triggers many collisions, and that's fine. **It's *not* ok to use someone's name and avatar**: that shows a deliberate attempt to pass for another user.

Stéphane Chazelas (the original) writes his username with the Unicode character U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE. Stéphane Chazelas (the newcomer) uses U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT. These are two ways to encode the same text in Unicode.

Note that in this case, the newcomer [is the same person as the original](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164416/how-can-i-remove-lines-matching-foo-but-not-matching-bar/164439#comment269901_164439), so this is not a case of impersonation. It's ok for someone to have two accounts as long as the accounts don't interact (no voting on each other's posts, etc.) — it's tricky to carry out, and the Stack Exchange team declines responsibility if the accounts end up being merged, but it isn't against the rules.

Comment: So why haven't the moderators done anything about that? Or have they? Has he himself made a second account? And why am I asking you this instead of him and the moderators...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Why haven't the moderators done anything about what? I don't see anything actionable here.

Comment: Haven't you just told me that "It's not ok to use someone's name and avatar"? So is there a sophisticated difference between "not OK" and "actionable"?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's ok if it's the same person doing it! It's not impersonation then.